# Import KML to Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, kml

Is is it possible to import a KML into Bing Maps "My Places"?

"My Places" let's you export a KML but I can't find the import option.

Comment: almost a candidate for webapps.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: didn't know that one, I'll try it next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found that Import only works in IE and not with Chrome.

Instructions: Open the "My Places" editor; The "Import" button is at the top, next to the "New List" button.

Comment: strange, that chrome is not supported.

Comment: It appeaqrs that this capability has been removed?